# Unable to fetch Gmail Contacts in Android app - Can fetch from Desktop Java App with same code

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

My Java Application is able to connect and fetch my gmail contacts but Android Application is throwing exception "Error connecting with login URI".

Here is the code from both applications. I tried Android App on emulator and Phone. In both, I get the same error. I can open pages in web browser in both (I meant, I have internet access). Please advise.

```
//Java Application Code
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, IOException {
    ContactsService service;
    URL feedUrl;
    ContactFeed resultFeed;
    String url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" + "contacts/"
            + "username@gmail.com" + "/thin";
    System.err.println("This is the url:" + url);
    try {
        feedUrl = new URL(url);
        service = new ContactsService("Google-contactsExampleApp-3");
        service.setUserCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");
        resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
        for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {

            if (entry.getTitle() != null) {

                System.err.println("Contact name: "
                        + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());

            } else {
                System.err.println("Contact has no name");

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

//Android Application Code
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    ContactsService service;
    URL feedUrl;
    ContactFeed resultFeed;

    String url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" + "contacts/"
            + "username@gmail.com" + "/thin";
    System.err.println("This is the url:" + url);
    try {
        feedUrl = new URL(url);
        service = new ContactsService("Google-contactsExampleApp-3");
        service.setUserCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");
        resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
        for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {

            if (entry.getTitle() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Contact name: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Contact has no name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("**** Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        //Exception: Error connecting with login URI

    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're allowed to use the network connection? Make sure this permission is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. Now I added it but have another exception.. W/XmlParser(514): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities

Any pointers?

Comment: I found this article..  http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/11/solution-for-gdata-java-clients.html. And it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 In android emulator you will find email application.You just click that and give the email Id and password.Login in to account.then run your code in emulator it will works
```